# How to find subgroups, fixed fields and subfields of Galois group?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Let $\Sigma$ be a splitting field in $\mathbb C$ of the polynomial $f(x)=x^4-49$ over $\mathbb Q$.

- Construct $\Sigma$ and find the degree of the field extension $\Sigma:\mathbb Q$.
- Determine the elements and the structure of the Galois group $\Gamma(\Sigma:\mathbb Q).$

> - Find all the subgroups of $\Gamma(\Sigma : \mathbb Q)$ and their fixed fields (justify answer).
> - Find all the subfields of $\Sigma$ (justify answer).

I think I've got the first two figured out with $\Sigma = \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 7)$ and $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt7)]=4$.

Every element $\gamma\in\Gamma(\Sigma:\mathbb Q)$ is completely and uniquely determined by the images $\gamma(\sqrt7)$ and $\gamma(i)$ which must be roots of $x^2-7$ and $x^2+1$ respectively. Thus we have $\gamma(\sqrt 7 )=\pm\sqrt 7$ and $\gamma(i)=\pm i$. Hence the Galois group has the structure of the Klein 4 group where its elements are the automorphisms:

$Id: \begin{cases}
    \sqrt7 \mapsto \sqrt7 \\
    i \mapsto i
  \end{cases}$

$\phi: \begin{cases}
    \sqrt7 \mapsto \sqrt7 \\
    i \mapsto -i
  \end{cases}$

$\psi: \begin{cases}
    \sqrt7 \mapsto -\sqrt7 \\
    i \mapsto i
  \end{cases}$

$\psi\phi: \begin{cases}
    \sqrt7 \mapsto -\sqrt7 \\
    i \mapsto -i
  \end{cases}$

- I'm struggling a little with part 3 and 4. If I had to guess I would say that the fixed fields were $\mathbb Q(i)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 7)$ and $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt 7)$ but I'm unsure how to completely prove it.

Could anyone offer any help for the last two parts?

Comment: @Leon Hendrian  $x^4-49=(x^2-7)(x^2+7)=(x+\sqrt{7})(x-\sqrt{7})(x+i\sqrt{7})(x-i\sqrt{7})$